# Can not install Optano Modeling in Xamarin solution

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, fparsec

I'm just starting out with Xamarin and trying to install this package 'Optano Modeling' into my Xamarin Forms solution via Nuget. But I keep getting this error when installing Optano modeling.

'Could not install package 'FParsec 1.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
'

I noticed FParsec is written in F# and my solution is in C#. Does anyone know if Optano Modeling / FParsec can be used in a Xamarin solution? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that one of the dependencies in a sub dependency (Math.NET Numerics for F#) wasn't compatible with the 'portable45-net45+win8+wpa81' configuration.